# How to filter values that input in numberdecimal EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an app with a single numberdecimal EditText. I want to make so that the user can not enter a value greater than 120.0. I do not know how to do this. However, I was able to make the input of numbers from 1 to 120 (without decimals).

Here is my code:

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilterMinMax(1,120)}); 

    public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

        private int min, max;

        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }
```